# Query for records where json key exists in Rails/Arel/Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, arel

On a hypothetical `books` table with a `json` column called `internal`, I want to summon the records that **do** and (separately) **do not** have a `rating` key.

Answer (score 2):

Exists:

```
Book.where('internal::jsonb ? :key', key: 'rating')
```

Do not exist:

```
Book.where.not('internal::jsonb ? :key', key: 'rating')
```

[See table called "Additional jsonb Operators"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html):

```
jsonb ? text → boolean
Does the text string exist as a top-level key or array element within the JSON value?
'{"a":1, "b":2}'::jsonb ? 'b' → t
'["a", "b", "c"]'::jsonb ? 'b' → t
```

Comment: But be careful when using the `?` operator with placeholders, you'll want to use named placeholders: `where('internal::jsonb ? :key', key: 'rating')`.